# Can Azure static web apps have Azure App Service as their backend?

Tags: angular, azure, cloud, azure-appservice, azure-static-web-app

I need to create a Azure static web app and let users download a file generated by an already existing Azure app service. Can static web apps communicate with Azure app services as their backend?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy an App with Rest-APIs as Azure App Service and use these Rest-APIs from your static web app

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: yes.

The slightly longer answer:

> ### API options
>
> The following Azure services can be integrated with Azure Static Web Apps:
>
> | Service | Managed | Bring your own |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Azure Functions | ✔ | ✔ |
> | Azure API Management |  | ✔ |
> | Azure App Service |  | ✔ |
> | Azure Container Apps |  | ✔ |
>
> ##### Note
>
> Bring your own APIs is only available in the Azure Static Web Apps Standard plan. Built-in, managed Azure Functions APIs are available in all Azure Static Web Apps plans.

*Source: [Overview of API support in Azure Static Web Apps - API options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-overview#api-options)*

> When you link your Azure App Service web app to your static web app, any requests to your static web app with a route that starts with `/api` are proxied to the same route on the Azure App Service app.
>
> By default, when an App Service app is linked to a static web app, the App Service app only accepts requests that are proxied through the linked static web app. An Azure App Service app can only be linked to a single static web app at a time.

Taken from the article that explains how to do this: [API support in Azure Static Web Apps with Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-app-service)

Comment: Can we link an already existing azure app service? @rickvdbosch

Comment: Can this be done using bicep?

Comment: That's a 'yes' on both questions!

Comment: If you could share a documentation about the above it will be really helpful

Comment: The documentation I linked to in my answer literally has a chapter called "Link an Azure App Service Web App". Start there.